# Sending Indefinite ping using Python and saving output in a text file

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, ping

I am new to Python programming and especially subprocess modules.

I have found some code online that sends ping command using python and stores its output in a file, but i am having difficulty in understanding how I can send indefinite amount of pings (basically ping 8.8.8.8 -t) and then simulate CTRl+C, so that output gets stored in text file.

Any resource links (instead of mulitple forums online), where I can get information would be helpful.

Using below code:

```
import subprocess
import time
import signal


out = open('output.txt', 'a')
p = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '8.8.8.8', '-t'], stdout = out)
time.sleep(10)
p.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
out.close()
```

I am getting error "raise ValueError("Unsupported signal: {}".format(sig))
ValueError: Unsupported signal: 2"

Thanks

Comment: what is wrong with `p.terminate()`?

Comment: i solved it, looking at some documentation found that instead of 'p.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)' i needed to use 'p.send_signal(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)'

Comment: Stephen, does p.terminate closes the process gracefully?

Comment: I tried with p.terminate, it does not save the final ouput of ping results, but i can do it via 'p.send_signal(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT). Thanks for responding.